# VBA Need to add a column to count occurrences in a sequence and reset on given value appearing

Tags: excel, vba

First of all apologies i know it this is for posting initial attempts and looking for assistance on solutions however i have no clue where to start on this

I am looking to create a macro in VBA that add two new columns to a table of data and fills each cell with a count created from data in another column. So it essentially counts a sequence.
For example in the below i have added the Counter Column which first increments a counter on the occurrence of the player in the winner column. It then resets when the Score value = 0-0 and starts again.

The Sequence column would then pick out the highest number in each sequence.

The reason i want to do this is so that i can then run a COUNTIFS on the table to see how many times a player has won points in a row - such as 3pts in a row = 2, 2pts in a row = 3, 1pt in a row = 7.

I hope that makes sense. I'm struggling to figure out the best way to do it, but it needs to be in VBA. I can run it on either the raw table of data or on an actual excel table version as i have access to both.

Thanks,

Simon

```
+-------+----------+---------+----------+
| Score |  Winner  | Counter | Sequence |
+-------+----------+---------+----------+
| 0-0   | Player 1 |       1 |          |
| 15-0  | Player 1 |       2 |          |
| 30-0  | Player 1 |       3 |          |
| 40-0  | Player 1 |       4 |        4 |
| 0-0   | Player 1 |       1 |        1 |
| 15-0  | Player 2 |       1 |          |
| 15-15 | Player 2 |       2 |        2 |
| 15-30 | Player 1 |       1 |          |
| 30-30 | Player 1 |       2 |          |
| 40-30 | Player 1 |       3 |        3 |
| 0-0   | Player 2 |       1 |          |
| 0-15  | Player 2 |       2 |        2 |
| 0-30  | Player 1 |       1 |        1 |
| 15-30 | Player 2 |       1 |          |
| 15-40 | Player 2 |       2 |        2 |
| 0-0   | Player 2 |       1 |          |
+-------+----------+---------+----------+
```

Comment: If you are going to be using worksheet functions (eg `COUNTIFS`) why **must** you use VBA??

Comment: @RonRosenfeld i need to do some pre-processing otherwise the formulas within the spreadsheet would become massive.

Answer (score 0):

The script I made might be terribly optimized, but I gave it a shot.

It should work assuming the data you want is in the first worksheet (sheets(1)) of your workbook. And assuming the data structure follows the example given by you (colA = SCORE, colB = WINNER, colC = COUNTER, colD = Sequence).

To execute the script just run main() sub procedure.
It calls addcounter sub (which work on colC, COUNTER), and then it calls addseq(colD, SEQUENCE)

For COUNTER, I have pretty much added a counter that will reset whenever both scores add up to 0 or player number change from 1 - 2 or vice-versa.

For SEQUENCE, it will count whenever a game is over (when there is a 40 in the score), or there is a player change.

I ran the script on my pc, and I got the same result on your given example.

Give it a try and get back to me in the comments to fix possible issues.

Please see code below,

```
Option Explicit

Dim wb As Workbook
Dim tRow As Long

Dim sRng As Range
Dim cel As Range

Dim tArr() As String
Dim contar As Long
Dim i As Long

Dim a As String
Dim b As String

Sub main()

'sets wb as active workbook
Set wb = ThisWorkbook

'calls procedure that sets up COUNTER col
Call addcounter

'calls second procedure that fills the SEQUENCE col
Call addseq

End Sub



Private Sub addcounter()

'counts last row to obtain ubound of table range
tRow = crow(1, 1)

'sets range based on total row count and col a, excluding header, starts from A2
Set sRng = wb.Sheets(1).Range("A2:A" & tRow)

'bad practice, but i used on error to ignore any data type error when comparing variables
On Error Resume Next

'iterate through all the cells in sRng set up above
For Each cel In sRng

    'splits string under SCORE, and removes the dash, and stores the data in tArr array
    tArr = Split(cel.Value, "-")
    
    'a and b variables obtain the player numbers for the winner change check
    a = Replace(cel.Offset(0, 1).Value, "Player", "")
    b = Replace(cel.Offset(-1, 1).Value, "Player", "")
    
    'check for sum of the both scores, if zero, it resets the count
    i = CLng(tArr(0)) + CLng(tArr(1))

    'checks for counter reset, it checks for sum of both score 0 or if player 1 & 2 changed
    If i = 0 Or pcheck(a, b) = False Then
    
        contar = 1
    
        cel.Offset(0, 2).Value = contar

    Else
    
        contar = contar + 1
    
        cel.Offset(0, 2).Value = contar
    
    End If

Next cel

Set sRng = Nothing
Set cel = Nothing

End Sub



Private Sub addseq()

'counts last row to obtain ubound of table range
tRow = crow(1, 1)


Set sRng = wb.Sheets(1).Range("A2:A" & tRow)

On Error Resume Next
contar = 1

'iterate through all the cells in sRng set up above
For Each cel In sRng

    tArr = Split(cel.Value, "-")
    
    a = Replace(cel.Offset(0, 1).Value, "Player", "")
    b = Replace(cel.Offset(1, 1).Value, "Player", "")
    
    
    If cel.Offset(1, 0) = "" Then
        
        Set sRng = Nothing
        Set cel = Nothing

        Exit Sub
    
    ElseIf (tArr(0) = 40 Or tArr(1) = 40) Or pcheck(a, b) = False Then
    
        cel.Offset(0, 3).Value = contar
    
        contar = 1
    
    Else

        contar = contar + 1

    End If
    
Next cel

Set sRng = Nothing
Set cel = Nothing

End Sub

'The Functions used are below:

Private Function crow(s As Variant, c As Integer) As Long


    crow = Sheets(s).Cells(Rows.Count, c).End(xlUp).Row


End Function



Private Function pcheck(ByVal a As Long, ByVal b As Long) As Boolean


    If a = b Then
    
        pcheck = True
    
    Else
    
        pcheck = False
    
    End If

End Function
```

The code is a little messy, but I got the same results based on the example above. any feedback on best practices would be welcome.

Thank you!

Comment: thanks for taking the time to do this. I have tried it out however it only fills the counter and sequence columns with 1s all the way down? I edited my table to match what i presented before for testing.

Comment: weird... it worked perfectly fine on my end after I tried several times. Is there a way I can reach out to help? Or you can try the others solutions above.

Answer (score 0):

### Get Counter Sequence

- You only run the first procedure, `runCounterSequence`.
- The second procedure, `getCounterSequence`, is being called by the first when needed.
- In this example, `A2` represents the first cell of the two-column data range, and `ColumnOffset = 2` means that the same-sized result will be written starting from cell `C2`.

**The Code**

```
Option Explicit

Sub runCounterSequence()
    
    ' Constants
    Const wsName As String = "Sheet1"
    Const FirstDataCell As String = "A2"
    Const ColumnOffset As Long = 2
    Dim wb As Workbook
    Set wb = ThisWorkbook ' The workbook containing this code.
    
    ' Define worksheet
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    On Error Resume Next
    Set ws = wb.Worksheets(wsName)
    On Error GoTo 0
    
    ' Validate worksheet.
    If ws Is Nothing Then
        GoTo ProcExit
    End If
    
    ' Transform values from Source Range to Data Array ('Data').
    Dim Data As Variant
    Data = getCounterSequence(ws, FirstDataCell)
    
    ' Validate Data Array.
    If IsEmpty(Data) Then
        GoTo ProcExit
    End If
    
    ' Define Target First Data Row Range ('rng').
    Dim rng As Range
    Set rng = ws.Range(FirstDataCell).Offset(, ColumnOffset).Resize(, 2)
    
    ' Write values from Data Array to Target Range.
    With cel
        ' Clear contents from Target First Data Row Range to the bottom.
        .Resize(ws.Rows.Count - rng.Row + 1).ClearContents
        ' Write values from Data Array to Target Range.
        .Resize(UBound(Data, 1)).Value = Data
    End With
    
    ' Inform user.
    MsgBox "Counter & Sequence written.", vbInformation, "Success"

ProcExit:

End Sub

''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''
' Purpose:      ?
' Remarks:      The result is a 2D two-column one-based array.
''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''
Function getCounterSequence(Sheet As Worksheet, _
                            Optional ByVal FirstDataCell As String = "A1") _
         As Variant
    
    ' Define Data Range ('rng')
    
    ' Validate worksheet.
    If Sheet Is Nothing Then
        GoTo ProcExit
    End If
    ' Validate First Data Cell (and define its row).
    On Error GoTo ProcExit
    Dim FirstRow As Long
    FirstRow = Sheet.Range(FirstDataCell).Row
    On Error GoTo 0
    ' Continue...
    Dim FirstCol As Long
    FirstCol = Sheet.Range(FirstDataCell).Column
    Dim LastRow As Long
    LastRow = Sheet.Cells(Sheet.Rows.Count, FirstCol).End(xlUp).Row
    ' Validate Last Non-Empty Row.
    If FirstRow > LastRow Then
        GoTo ProcExit
    End If
    ' Continue...
    Dim rng As Range
    Set rng = Sheet.Range(FirstDataCell).Resize(LastRow - FirstRow + 1, 2)
    Dim DataCount As Long
    DataCount = rng.Rows.Count
    
    ' Write values from Data Range to Data Array ('Data').
    
    Dim Data As Variant
    Data = rng.Value
    
    ' Modify values in Data Array.
    
    ' Modify first row.
    Dim Previous As String
    Data(1, 1) = 1
    Previous = Data(1, 2)
    Data(1, 2) = Empty
    If DataCount = 1 Then
        GoTo writeResult
    End If
    ' Modify remaining rows.
    Dim i As Long
    For i = 2 To DataCount
        If Data(i, 1) = "0-0" Then
            Data(i, 1) = 1
            Previous = Data(i, 2)
            Data(i - 1, 2) = Data(i - 1, 1)
        Else ' Data(i, 1) <> "0-0"
            If Data(i, 2) = Previous Then
                Data(i, 1) = Data(i - 1, 1) + 1
            Else ' Data(i, 2) <> Previous
                Data(i, 1) = 1
                Previous = Data(i, 2)
                Data(i - 1, 2) = Data(i - 1, 1)
            End If
        End If
        Data(i, 2) = Empty
    Next i
 
    ' Write result.

writeResult:
    getCounterSequence = Data
    
ProcExit:

End Function
```

Answer (score 0):

If you have a lot of pre-processing to do, it might be simpler in `Power Query` than `VBA`, but here is a `VBA` routine that is more complex than necessary (see below for a simplified version), but should give you an idea of how to use Classes so as to perhaps give you some hints on how to pre-process your data, as you mentioned in a comment.

- I used a Dictionary object to sort out and help create the necessary sequences.
- I also used a Class (object) to contain the items for each sequence.
- I used a vba Array to contain and process the data as this is MUCH faster than multiple worksheet read/write sequences.

Be sure to either **Set a Reference** `Tools/References` to `Microsoft Scripting Runtime` or convert the references to late binding.

- Add a Class module and rename it `cScores`

**Class Module**

```
Option Explicit
Private pScore As String
Private pScores As Dictionary
Private pWinner As String

Public Property Get Score() As String
    Score = pScore
End Property
Public Property Let Score(Value As String)
    pScore = Value
End Property

Public Property Get Scores() As Dictionary
    Set Scores = pScores
End Property
Public Function addScoresItem(Value)
    If pScores.Exists(Value) Then
        MsgBox "Duplicate key will not be added"
    Else
        pScores.Add Value, Value
    End If
End Function

Public Property Get Winner() As String
    Winner = pWinner
End Property
Public Property Let Winner(Value As String)
    pWinner = Value
End Property

Private Sub Class_Initialize()
    Set pScores = New Dictionary
End Sub
```

- Add a Regular Module

```
'Set reference to Microsoft Scripting Runtime
Option Explicit
Sub PlayerScoring()
    Dim wsSrc As Worksheet
    Dim vData As Variant
    Dim lKey As Long
    Dim dS As Dictionary, cS As cScores
    Dim I As Long, J As Long, v
    
'Set source and results worksheet and ranges
'read source data into VBA array for faster processing
Set wsSrc = Worksheets("Sheet1")
With wsSrc
    'this is one of many ways to find the relevant range.
    vData = .Cells(1, 1).CurrentRegion.Resize(columnsize:=4)
    vData(1, 3) = "Counter"
    vData(1, 4) = "Sequence"
End With


'split up the relevant data for each sequence
'and store in dictionary so as to easily count
Set dS = New Dictionary
lKey = 0
For I = 2 To UBound(vData)
    Set cS = New cScores
    If vData(I, 1) = "0-0" Or vData(I, 2) <> vData(I - 1, 2) Then lKey = lKey + 1
    If Not dS.Exists(lKey) Then
        With cS
            .Score = vData(I, 1)
            .Winner = vData(I, 2)
            .addScoresItem .Score
            dS.Add Key:=lKey, Item:=cS
        End With
    Else
        dS(lKey).addScoresItem vData(I, 1)
    End If
Next I

'Populate results
I = 2
For Each v In dS
    With dS(v)
        'populate counter
        For J = 0 To .Scores.Count
        
            'check for last entry
            If I + J > UBound(vData) Then
                J = J + 1
                Exit For
            End If
            
            vData(I + J, 3) = J + 1
        Next J
        'populate sequence
        vData(I + J - 2, 4) = .Scores.Count
        I = I + J - 1
    End With
Next v
    
Dim rRes As Range
Set rRes = wsSrc.Cells(1, 12).Resize(rowsize:=UBound(vData, 1), columnsize:=UBound(vData, 2))
With rRes
    .EntireColumn.Clear
    .Value = vData
    .Style = "output"
    .EntireColumn.AutoFit
End With

End Sub
```

- Change the Worksheet and Results references to reflect your data table
- As written, the results will NOT overwrite the original.

  - Once you are satisfied it is working OK, you can change the reference so that it does.

[image]

**EDIT:**

The above code can be simplified. I wrote it with a class module to give you an idea of what can be done so, perhaps, you can do something similar with what you have to pre-process.

But to obtain **ONLY** the results you need, you just need to store the respective Counts for each grouping in a Dictionary, and then output the results similar to the method above.

eg:  Add only this **Regular Module**

```
Option Explicit
Sub PlayerScoring()
    Dim wsSrc As Worksheet, rRes As Range
    Dim vData As Variant, vRes As Variant
    Dim lKey As Long
    Dim dS As Dictionary
    Dim I As Long, J As Long, v
    
'Set source and results worksheet and ranges
'read source data into VBA array for faster processing
Set wsSrc = Worksheets("Sheet1")
With wsSrc
    'this is one of many ways to find the relevant range.
    vData = Range(.Cells(1, 1), .Cells(.Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp)).Resize(columnsize:=2)
    ReDim vRes(1 To UBound(vData, 1), 1 To UBound(vData, 2))
        vRes(1, 1) = "Counter"
        vRes(1, 2) = "Sequence"
    Set rRes = Range(.Cells(1, 3), .Cells(UBound(vData, 1), 4))
End With


'split up the relevant data for each sequence
'and store in dictionary so as to easily count
Set dS = New Dictionary
lKey = 0
For I = 2 To UBound(vData)
    If vData(I, 1) = "0-0" Or vData(I, 2) <> vData(I - 1, 2) Then lKey = lKey + 1
    If Not dS.Exists(lKey) Then
            dS.Add Key:=lKey, Item:=1
    Else
        dS(lKey) = dS(lKey) + 1
    End If
Next I

'Populate results
I = 2
For Each v In dS
    With dS(v)
        'populate counter
        For J = 0 To dS(v)
        
            'check for last entry
            If I + J > UBound(vData) Then
                J = J + 1
                Exit For
            End If
            
            vRes(I + J, 1) = J + 1
        Next J
        'populate sequence
        vRes(I + J - 2, 2) = dS(v)
        I = I + J - 1
    End With
Next v
    

With rRes
    .EntireColumn.Clear
    .Value = vRes
    .EntireColumn.AutoFit
End With

End Sub
```

Comment: thanks for this. I think i will take a look at your regular module version, looks easier for me to understand for now. I'm going to play about with it tomorrow and try to adjust it to work with my named columns as they won't be position next to each as in the example. It constantly changes so i need to use column titles to find the correct ones. I'll let you know how i go. Thanks again for the help.